How to sum assigned scores of multiple rasters into an output raster in Raster Calculator
I'm using ArcGIS Pro. I have multiple rasters, each representing a water quality characteristic. I assigned a score for each characteristic. A couple rasters have different scores. I want to overlay the rasters that sums the scores. I want the outout raster be a sum of the scores. I have tried simply adding the rasters in Raster Calculator but the output raster just did an intersection; the scores were not included.
In this screen show, you will see the scores for the different rasters. I would like the output to sum these scores.


https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm

Use lookup first to create scores rasters?

To clarify, each water quality characteristic (raster) has a weight, and you want to sum the weighted scores? Or do you mean you want to normalized the values so that (for example) every raster's values were put on a scale of 0-1?

You are on the right track in terms of summing the scores using the Raster Calculator. The fact that the raster calculator is performing an intersection rather than properly carrying out the simple arithmetic you inputted suggests to me that either 1.) you have null values in your raster dataset which need removal or 2.) the raster layers you are using are not properly aligned and need to be resampled.
In order to fix this, I would first simply perform a selection filter in order to identify any null values. To do this, grab the "select by attribute" tool, and build a query for IF WaterScore is NULL. If no values are selected, move on to the next step. If you do find Null values, you should either recalculate or assign a zero, depending on the original dataset.
Now, assuming there aren't any null values in the dataset, we can discuss raster alignment. The raster calculator requires an explicit setting of cell size and extent in order to work. If rasters vary in these measurements, then by default the calculator will only work in areas where the raster cells overlap, resulting in an intersection as you described. To fix this, you can set a global extent and cell size for all the rasters you wish to work with. In order to do this, you set the "processing extent" in the environment settings to the union of all rasters, while setting "cell size" to the smallest common resolution (the smallest common resolution would be the largest cell size used in any of the raster images). Additionally, for any rasters which do not have a higher resolution (and therefore have a smaller cell size), you need to use the "resample" tool which will allow you to adjust cell sizes/resolution. Set all rasters to the cell size which you have defined in the environment settings. Finally, return to the environment settings and set the "Snap Raster" input to the raster from which you derived the smallest common resolution.
Now your data has been cleaned, and your rasters are properly aligned and sharing a common resolution. This should allow the raster calculator to run it's operation smoothly.
